# Return a lambda from a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, return-type-deduction

I want to use a lambda to evaluate (switch-case) some conditions and return a lambda accordingly.

```
const auto lmb1 = []() {
    printf("1\n");
};

const auto lmb2 = []() {
    printf("2\n");
};

const auto select = [](auto const &ref) {
  switch(ref) {
      case 1: return lmb1;
      case 2: return lmb2;
  }
  
    
};

std::function foo = select(1);

foo();
```

Sadly things aren't working.
What I am doint wrong?

Comment: Don't just say "things aren't working" - provide a proper [mre]  and include the exact problems (e.g.: compiler error messages)

Comment: @UnholySheep issue is obvious. He should add `lmb1` and `lmb2` to capture list of `select` and explicitly define return type of `select`.

Comment: even though this code is easy to fix I prefer to see more background of this code, since I do not want to teach how to write hard to maintain code. With more background I could provide code which would be more clear.

Comment: `lmb1` and `lmbd2` have *different* types. Also, `select` is a Linux API, don't name a variable this name.

Comment: That is why I've wrote `explicitly define return type of select`.

Comment: @MarekR As it happens, the issues (plural) are [less obvious than you might think](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1QHBcdgrBykwtxqc).

Comment: Lambda in global scope! It is so stupid I didn't think about that.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Comment: 康桓瑋: Using an identifier that is used somewhere else is perfectly OK as long as you do not include the header defining that identifier. If everyone would have to stay away from all function names ever declared, the available namespace would be pretty sparse. OP might not even work on Linux for all we know.

Comment: @MarekR: What do you mean with "Lambda in global scope! It is so stupid I didn't think about that."

Comment: 1. Global variables are bad in general (lambda or not lambda). 2. lambda in global scope behaves just like a function, so it is better to define a old fashioned function.

Comment: And it seems that a free function has a smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that a lambda, by default, deduce (as an `auto` function) the returned type and in your lambda you return two different lambdas. Every lambda has a different type, so the compiler can't choose a type for the returned lambda

```
[](auto const &ref) {
  switch(ref) {
      case 1: return lmb1; //    decltype(lmb1) 
      case 2: return lmb2; // != decltype(lmb2)
  }  
};
```

You can solve the problem in different ways.

1. You can explicit the lambda returned type, using a type that both `lmb1` and `lmb2` can be converted to (in this example, `std::function<void()>` or also `void(*)()`). When that type is available

   ```
   // -----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
   [](auto const &ref) -> std::function<void()> {
        switch(ref) {
            case 1: return lmb1; 
            case 2: return lmb2;
        }  
   };
   ```
2. You can explicitly convert the returned values to a common type. Again: when a common type is available

   ```
   [](auto const &ref)
   {
       switch(ref) { // --V
           case 1: return +lmb1; // with the '+', lmb1 is converted to a void(*)()
           case 2: return +lmb2; // with the '+', lmb2 is converted to a void(*)()
   }     // --------------^
   ```
3. If the `ref` argument can be a template value, starting from [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can define a template lambda and, using `if constexpr`, you can return different types from different lambdas. This works also when there isn't a common type (*but require a compile-time known argument*)

   ```
   const auto selct = []<int REF>(std::integral_constant<int, REF>) {
     if constexpr ( 1 == REF )
       return lmb1;
     else
       return lmb2;
   };

   auto foo = selct(std::integral_constant<int, 1>{});
   ```